# difference between developing for iphone 3gs and for iphone 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-4, iphone-3gs

I've developed application for the original iPhone, the 3G and the 3GS, now I need to develop an application for the iPhone 4. What is the difference between developing an application for iPhone 3GS and the iPhone 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most noticeable change is the [Retina Display](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and you should include [@2x images](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html) in your project to support this. Other than that unless you plan on taking advantage of new hardware (gyroscope for example) or the graphics and cpu improvements, there is very little difference. Also you should reference the [SDK Compatibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163-BCICHGIE) for tips on maintaining backwards compatibility and/or supporting features available only on certain devices.

Comment: Just be sure to include a retina version of the images used in the UI. The retina version are just the same image but twice the size (10x10 becomes 20x20) and add @2x just before the extension.

Comment: Do not forget the retina display (doubled resolution).

Comment: So I will develop for iphone 4 like I did for iphone 3gs?

Comment: Just adding new images with size 20x20 except 10x10.

Comment: what about interface builder it will atomatically rescale my views to iphone4 resolution?

Comment: If you include the Hi Resolution images, your interface builder files will automatically include the higher res version on devices that support it. See [updating your resource files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8).

Comment: What will happen with graphics if I launch iphone3gs application on iphone4? everything will be the same but the graphics will be a bit ugly? or much ugly?

Comment: Your current application without bundling the hi res graphics will look a bit blurry.

Comment: @Joe If I include image.png and image@2x.png to my project. What image should I set here: `[UIImage imageNamed:/*here*/]` or in interface builder? only the image.png and xcode will automatically search for image@2x.png when an application will be launched on retina desplay?

Comment: The image you set there will be "image.png", the SDK will handle finding the correct @2x/~iphone/~ipad image for you. Always just specify the original images name.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 3GS uses a 480-by-320-pixel resolution screen where as the iPhone 4 (and 4S) uses a 960-by-640-pixel resolution screen.

As @Joe says, there is very little other differences.